# Heroku + Facebook: Invalid redirect_uri: Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, authentication, heroku

I deployed to Heroku a staging version of a Rails app, I am using Devise gem and in the **/config/initializers/devise.rb** I am storing credentials, like this:

```
# production
  config.omniauth :facebook, '11', '22',
      :site              => 'https://graph.facebook.com',
      :authorize_path    => '/oauth/authorize',
      :access_token_path => '/oauth/access_token',
      :scope => 'email, publish_stream, read_friendlists'

  # staging
  config.omniauth :facebook, '33', '44',
      :site              => 'https://graph.facebook.com',
      :authorize_path    => '/oauth/authorize',
      :access_token_path => '/oauth/access_token',
      :scope => 'email, publish_stream, read_friendlists'
  # localhost
  config.omniauth :facebook, '55', '66',
      :site              => 'https://graph.facebook.com',
      :authorize_path    => '/oauth/authorize',
      :access_token_path => '/oauth/access_token',
      :scope => 'email, publish_stream, read_friendlists'
```

Localhost and production are working well, but the staging version isn't. I use exactly the same setup in the Facebook administration as for production as for staging version, but the staging version still return this error message:

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "Invalid redirect_uri: Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 191
   }
}
```

It drives me crazy, because for 2 environments it's working, but not for the third one (for staging).  Any tips what could be wrong?

Comment: Make sure that in the FB administration for the Staging app your Site URL is actually pointing to the staging and not production.

Comment: Sure, there is the "Site URL" set up this way: `https://staging-app.herokuapp.com`. "App Domains" is empty, credentials in the app are set up correctly.